# Generating requirements.txt from mounted filesystem?

Tags: python, linux, pip, requirements.txt

My Ubuntu OS had some problem so I mounted it on a recovery(temporary) OS. Now I have access to all my previous files from the path `/mnt`(e.g. the 'home' folder will be at `/mnt/home/`).

I need to generate a `requirements.txt` file of all the Python2.7 libraries installed in my previous OS. If is use `pip freeze`, I get the list of libraries of only the current OS.

How do I generate the `requirements.txt` from a mounted filesystem?

Comment: may be this will work. `/mnt/path/of/pip freeze > requirement.txt`

Comment: I tried that but I get this error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can execute a chroot inside your  mount point for example

```
chroot /mnt
```

and after execute:

```
pip freeze
```

for show the system library you can execute:

```
dpkg -l | grep python
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `/mnt pip freeze > requirements.txt` and it worked :-)